# QGIS small text with OSMon on a 4K laptop screen

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling

With a 4K laptop display (Dell 9710) when bringing in OSM maps with OSM Standard, OpenStreet Map, with EPSG:3857, the text labels at any level of scale are tiny, almost impossible to read. The project CRS is set to EPSG:3857. When the tiles are first loading, the text is larger, and then snaps to tiny sizes as the map resolution increases.

Also on a possibly related front, the OMS maps seem to lack contrast; the topography appears to be primarily gray, with green and yellow for parks, etc.

In the Coordinate window in the bottom of the screen, QDIS diaplays two numbers, 7 digits each, separated by a comma. These numbers appear to be unrelated to latitude or longitude.

Comment: Have you checked with OSM? Do they provide info on this issue?

Comment: In QGIS option>Canvas&Legend there is an option to "Respect screen DPI" does changing this setting have any effect ?

Comment: The coordinate window probably display easting and northing (X,Y) for EPSG:3857, so 7 digits number are not out of place, if you want lat/lon this could be modified in the project setting. This has nothing to do with your display problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Here's my post to the OSM forum... https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/how-to-enlarge-and-clarify-text-when-using-osm-in-qgis-with-a-4k-screen/100853

The "Respect screen DPI" option doesn't seem to help, and thanks also for the explanation for the easting display. Fuzzy and tiny text has been a problem in the past, with various fixes which don't seem to help.